# Object becoming null after leaving base class in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dynamic

I am trying to reduce code from the data layer (Class Library) of a project by making a generic DAO class with virtual methods, this way I will have implementations of this class for the various types needed.

For simplicity's sake I will only write the read method for all classes and only the necessary parameters.

One requirement is the object used as return for all methods within this layer, which is a generic class as below:

```
public class ReturnObject<T>
{
    public T Object { get; set; }
}
```

I started with an interface IDao:

```
public interface IDao<T>
{
    ReturnObject<T> Read(Guid id);
}
```

And then, the "default implementation":

```
public abstract class Dao<T> : IDao<T>
{
    // Database context.
    protected Context Context { get; } = new Context();

    public virtual ReturnObject<T> Read(Guid id)
    {
        // Creating return object.
        var returnObject = new ReturnObject<dynamic>();

        // Reading entity from database.
        try
        {
            switch (typeof(T).ToString())
            {
                case "Foo":
                    returnObject.Object = Context.Foos.First(o => o.Id == id) as dynamic;
                    break;

                case "Bar":
                    returnObject.Object = Context.Bars.First(o => o.Id == id) as dynamic;
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ...
        }
        finally
        {
            ...
        }

        // Returning result.
        return returnObject as ReturnObject<T>;
    }
}
```

So, basically this is the code reduction I'm trying to get. Based on the **T** class type I will be able to switch the proper set from the context, store the read object into the returnObject and then send it back to the caller.

For organization and other reasons, I also have several inherited classes, like this:

```
public class DaoFoo : Dao<Foo>
{
}
```

And finally, my problem. I'm positive I'm misinterpreting some concepts here and that's why I'm getting null values when calling the method read as exampled below:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid id)
    {
        var foo= new DaoFoo().Read(id);

        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, new foo.Object); 
    }
}
```

When debugging I can see that the **Dao** class is sending the right object, with all its parameters, like in the image:

[image]

However, the calling method always gets **null**, like in the image:

[image]

With all that said, can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: just a wild guess, but if `returnObject != null` and `returnObject as ReturnObject<T> == null` then `returnObject` might not be an instance of `ReturnObject<T>`

Comment: Well, I just tested your theory, and... We have a winner! any thoughts on how to fix, or what is the proper way of doing this?
[link](https://s21.postimg.org/r2oo0pn5z/Untitlbvfdabrf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cast dynamic as ReturnObject which results in null, because it cannot cast one type to another.

Try not using dynamic, your method is generic so use T instead, so you dont have to cast

Comment: Thank you, the **dynamic** is required, otherwise the code won't compile, the problem is that I misplaced it. So I fallowed your suggestion and made a few tweaks, and now it’s working flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

`returnObject` is a `ReturnObject<object>`, but `returnObject as ReturnObject<T>` is null.  The `as` operator will return null if the provided value isn't of the specified type.